# How to do logical test for multiple criteria (numerical values and text) then display entire row if criteria are met

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I want to be able to do a logical test on size and region of property. If I input minimum size, maximum size and area into my criteria box, I need excel to display all properties that meet these criteria from the list that is on the same spreadsheet. I don't have a problem with logical test for size but I can't get an if(and() statement to check if text in the criteria box and on the list are the same and then to display that entire row i.e. property details if all criteria are met. I would also like the output list not to have gaps where criteria aren't met.

Answer (score 0):

How I would normally do this I would nest the if functions in each other try drawing a block diagram and then starting from the top nest the if functions to get the required results it will essentially be an if function in an if function.